# What malicious or supicious inbound and outbound rules in Windows Firewall should I block? Sorry, I am little paranoid

Tags: networking, windows-10, security, windows-firewall

When looking at the various inbound and outbound rules in window 10 firewall. I was unable to locate a list of malicious programs that created inbound and outbound rules for themselves.  I noticed all these things that I did not recognize in the Inbound and Outbound rules.  I resorted to Windows Firewall to block some connections that kept reappearing in netstat even though I added them to the hosts file.  Sorry, maybe I am overly paranoid, but please help me out.

Comment: Can you provide specifics?

Answer (score 3):

This is a fools errand.

If a program is actually malicious its developer can easily change the executable name and change the ports over which it communicates, thereby bypassing whatever static rules you've configured.

If you insist on using the firewall, then block ALL connections and ALL ports except those you explicitly allow.

See here: [How make windows 7 firewall block all traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/599743/how-make-windows-7-firewall-block-all-traffic)

A better way is to use Google to research those connections and applications to learn if they actually are malicious, and then if appropriate removing the programs and using your antivirus software to police the system.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you don't have any special program that need to listen a port to work (such as http or ftp server), then you can disable ALL rules, you can even lock down your firewall to disallow any exceptions. And these won't affect most of your daily use, you can use any browser perfectly normal.

Paranoid is good, from security point, if you don't know some function well, it's better to lock down it instead of open it up for attackers.